# The values must be of a collection type from the Collections Framework

Tags: java, collections, frameworks

Example scenario:

A Map with Strings that are Keys and represent peoples Names.
The values are Sets of Strings and each String represents a Car they own.

What does it mean to say values must be of collection type. I don't get it, are they not collection type when in the collection. For instance are the Strings not collection type when in the Set collection. Could someone explain that sentence?

Comment: Could you post some code that's giving you this error?

Answer (score 0):

> What does it mean to say values must be of collection type

Perhaps you are referring to the `values()` method of the `Map` interface.

Regardless of what the type of a single value in the `Map` may be (`Integer`, `String`, `Set<String>`, etc...), when you call the `values()` method, which returns all the values stored in the `Map`, you get a `Collection` of these values.

For example, in the case of your:

```
Map<String,Set<String>> map;
```

calling `values()` will give you a:

```
Collection<Set<String>> values = map.values();
```

The reasons a general `Collection` is returned here are:

1. Values don't have to be unique (there can be duplicates), so we can't return a `Set` of values.
2. Values don't have to be ordered (this the entries of a `Map` don't have to be ordered), so returning a `List` of values doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Java Collections is a general class framework on top of data structures such as lists, sets, maps and more. Collections has a large number of methods defined, which can operate on a number of actual data structures. The well-developed casting and overriding mechanism in Java ensures that the appropriate data structures are converted to, before a general collections method is being called.

There are also special collection types, like immutable maps and immutable lists.

All-in-all the Collections framework allows Java developers to apply a large set of well-known operators (methods) to many structured data types. You can read the book on OCP, where one chapter is devoted completely to the collections framework.